# TENSORFLOW DATASET API: cannot load image "cannot iterate over a scalar tensor"

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dataset, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

im new learning how to use tensorflow and i'd like to know how to plot my images, i tried to convert my tensor to np array but didnt work. My code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf        
import numpy  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import os  


dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('ai minecraft ores dataset/*/*', shuffle=False)

for files in dataset.take(3):   
        print(files.numpy()) 

def etiquetar(ubicacion_archivo):  
        return tf.strings.split(ubicacion_archivo, os.path.sep)[-2]

def procesar_imagen(ubicacion_archivo):  
        etiqueta = etiquetar(ubicacion_archivo)  
        imagen = tf.io.read_file(ubicacion_archivo)  
        imagen = tf.image.resize(imagen, [128,128])  
        return imagen, etiqueta
    

for imagen, etiqueta in dataset.map(procesar_imagen).take(3):  
        print(imagen) #esto imprimira el tensor RGB de la imagen  
        print(etiqueta)

dataset1 = dataset.map(procesar_imagen)  
for imagen, etiqueta in dataset1.take(3):  
        print(imagen.numpy().shape, etiqueta.numpy().decode())


plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))  
for imagen, etiqueta in dataset:  
  for i in range(9):  
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)  
    plt.imshow((imagen[i].numpy().astype("uint8")))  
    plt.title(class_names[etiqueta[i].numpy])  
    plt.axis("off")
```

and then i get the error.

Comment: can you indicate on which line the error appeared?

Comment: hey, thanks for your response! i got my error in line 50:  "for imagen, etiqueta in dataset:" -----
File "C:\Users\PC1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 578, in __iter__
    raise TypeError("Cannot iterate over a scalar tensor.")
TypeError: Cannot iterate over a scalar tensor.